# Initializing variables in Java as instances of different classes but same initializing keyword

Tags: java

I am new to Java and I finally faced with a problem that I have been postponing for a long time.

I was learning LinkedLists in Java and have the following confusion, please check:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class LinkedListDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> myList = new LinkedList<Integer>();

        myList.add(1);
        myList.add(22);
        myList.add(42);

        Iterator it = myList.iterator();

        while(it.hasNext()){
            if((int)(it.next()) == 42)
                System.out.println("We found 42");
        }

        myList.remove();
        System.out.println(myList);
    }
}
```

Here myList.remove(); gives the following error : "cannot resolve the method 'remove'."

however, if I instantiate myList variable like this

```
LinkedList<Integer> myList = new LinkedList<Integer>();
```

I don't have the same error and my code compiles successfully.

I just want to know the working behind this. I mean sometimes I declare ArrayList variables with

```
List myList = new ArrayList<>();
```

should I instead declare like this?

```
ArrayList myList = new ArrayList<>();
```

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Separate abstraction from implementation

Separate abstraction from implementation allows to code thinking in "I know I'll need here and there a `List`, but I still don't know/want to choose which kind of `List` at this moment" or: "I'd like to keep my options open to any `List` implementation here and there in my code". This is good thing to ease coding.

`LinkedList` and `ArrayList` are less abstract than `List`, which means that these are different implementations of `List`. Usually you will prefer to use more abstract classes, like `List` on this case, to separate abstraction from implementation, which is usually a good thing, e.g. to play with different implementations without changing the rest of your code. So:

```
List<Integer> myCoolList = new LinkedList<Integer>()
```

is usually better (as it promotes separation between abstraction and implementation, which is a good habit for your code) than:

```
LinkedList<Integer> myCoolList = new LinkedList<Integer>()
```

Now, if you choose to separate abstraction from implementation, of course you will lose the power to use methods specific for each implementation. But usually the most general class (in this case, `List`) will give enough alternatives to replace the lost methods ( the `LinkedList.remove()` method in this case)

Comment: I see. I am a little confused by "less abstract" term. You mean this because LinkedList and ArrayList classes implements List interface?

Answer (score 1):

Typically your remove method should have parameters.

Comment: remove is an overloaded method, you need to introduce the object or index to be deleted

Comment: Well said. I think I gave too much information in my question and have led it astray. The main thing I wanted to ask is what's the main difference between LinkedList<Integer> myList = new LinkedList<Integer>; and List<Integer> myList = new LinkedList<Integer>;

Comment: Yes, I understand what you want to know. In fact, this is caused by the inheritance relationship of JAVA. You can read another reply I gave you.

Answer (score 1):

The List interface doesn't have any **remove()** method without params.

So when your compiler statically checks your code, cannot find a matching method.

On the other hand, LinkedList has it. So that's why your code works.

Check the java docs for **List** and the **LinkedList**.

[List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

[LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can check the original code of the link, you can see that it has a remove() method that does not contain any parameters:

```
 /**
 * Retrieves and removes the head (first element) of this list.
 *
 * @return the head of this list
 * @throws NoSuchElementException if this list is empty
 * @since 1.5
 */
public E remove() {
    return removeFirst();
}
```

However, this remove() method does not exist in the List class, the parent class of LinkedList, so when you declare in this way:

```
 List<Integer> myList = new LinkedList<Integer>();
```

You will not be able to use the remove() method.

But if you use LinkedList initialization, then you will be able to use it, because remove() is unique to the subclass LinkedList.

```
 LinkedList<Integer> myList = new LinkedList<Integer>();
```